# Git tool `tig`: What do those letters in the graph mean?

Tags: git, git-branch, tig

When I run `tig`, I see a graph of the branches. It uses letters on those lines to show what happened there:

- “o” means commit
- “M“ is a merge
- “I” is a merge

What is the difference between “M” and “I”?

Comment: Add a screenshot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The I is labelled as `initial` in `tig` [source code](https://github.com/jonas/tig/blob/86a95a39d121b85ba19d10f717ded77db6299ee6/src/graph.c)

It seems it marks the initial commit (common ancestor) of a merge.
The M marks the merging commit.

Comment: That might be.  And checking it out I found a bug in the graph generation in `tig`. Some lines were not drawn...